# Adding Anchor to every module in Joomla 3.1

Tags: php, joomla, anchor

I am trying to modify the module template code to add an anchor to the title of each module.  I have extremely limited PHP knowledge, so any guidance would be very helpful.

I've found posts for doing this with articles, but the code appears to be very different for modules.

This is the code that is in my module template.

```
function modChrome_basic($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
    <?php echo $module->content; ?>
<?php endif;
}

function modChrome_standard($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
       <div class="rt-block <?php if ($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')!='') : ?><?php echo              $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?><?php endif; ?>">
        <div class="module-surround">
            <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
        <div class="module-title">
                <?php 
                echo '<h2 class="title">';
                    if (preg_match("/icon[-]{1,}/i", $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'))) : 
                        echo '<span class="title-icon ' .getIconClass($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')). '"></span>';
                    endif;
                    echo $module->title;
                echo '</h2>';
                ?>
        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="module-content">
                        <?php echo $module->content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
       </div>
<?php endif;
```

}
This is the code I tried

```
if( strlen($this->item->params->get('title')) > 0 ) { 
    echo '<a name="'.$this->item->params->get('title').'"></a>'; 
}
```

I also tried

```
 if( strlen($module->item->params->get('title')) > 0 ) { 
     echo '<a name="'.$module->item->params->get('title').'"></a>'; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code to go with this to help describe exactly what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a very small amount of PHP knowledge.  Here is an blog post that explains doing it for articles. I am trying to use the module title though - as I don't think modules have a key reference.   http://www.buildajoomlawebsite.com/blog/tutorial/create-anchor-links-to-article-titles

Comment: We do not do all your work for you here at Stackoverflow. We expect you (knowledge or no knowledge) to show some effort by at least attempting to solve your issue. There are tutorials out there that will show you how to make a module override.

Comment: I understand that, but I also realize this is a very simple task with the right knowledge.  This is the code I tried <?PHP if( strlen($this->item->params->get('title')) > 0 ) { echo '<a name="'.$this->item->params->get('title').'"></a>'; }  ?>

Comment: I also tried <?PHP if( strlen($module->item->params->get('title')) > 0 ) { echo '<a name="'.$module->item->params->get('title').'"></a>'; }  ?>

Comment: This is not PHP knowledge, it's Joomla knowledge. Find out what you can get with that `get()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has an easy way to customize the module appearance.

You have to use a [Custom module chrome](http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome).

You have to create a `modules.php` file under `/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/modules.php`.

Inside this file you have to put:

```
<?php
  function modChrome_custom( $module, &$params, &$attribs ) {

    echo '<div id="' .$params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ) .'" >';

    if ($module->showtitle) 
    {
    echo '<h' .$headerLevel .'>' .$module->title .'</h' .$headerLevel .'>';
    }

    echo '<div class="module_content">';
    echo $module->content;
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
```

In the code above the module id getting `moduleclass_sfx` value. You could change it and set another module variable.

In order to use this appearence you have to set the appropriate `style` to the template module calls like: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="custom" />`

If you want to use another style name you have to change the function from `modChrome_custom` to `modChrome_NEWSTYLE`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I have similar code already (using an existing template), but I do not know how to echo the title in an anchor.    I will edit my main post to show that code.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean by 'anchor'. Your code <a name=""> doesn't have an effect, you have to convert it to <a href="">.

Comment: Well my code right now produces an error, but I am trying to create an anchor tag in the code (not a link to an anchor). Eg:     <a name="anchor"></a>

Comment: please try with: <a name="'.$module->title.'"></a>

Comment: Part of the problem may be where I'm putting my code, but that didn't seem to work. If I put it after the module title div tag then it causes an error.  If I put it before that, then my code shows up as text on the website.

Comment: Please try to change echo '<h2 class="title">'; to echo '<h2 class="title"><a name="'.$module->title.'">'; and echo '</h2>'; to echo '</a></h2>';.